# How to successfully Sign up user and write to firebase firestore db?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm using firebase as my back-end and i'm trying to create User function that writes to my firestore db but I keep running to errors when testing out my functions after deploy.

Here's my code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { firebaseConfig } = require('firebase-functions');
const { request } = require('express');
// const { admin } = require('firebase-admin/lib/database');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let db = admin.firestore();



/*******************************
 *                             *
 *          INDIVIDUAL         * 
 *                             * 
 *******************************/

 //Creating a function that will create a Individual user with email & password
 // ???: Blair has implemented this in the front end, so likely will not use this function.
 exports.createIndividual = functions.https.onRequest((request, Response) =>
 {
     firebase.auth().createUser(email, password).catch(function(error) 
     {
        // Handle Errors here.
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
      });
 })

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});


// Trigger by new user in Firebase: adds their email and UID to the Individuals table for future reference. 
// Also Sets the Document name to the user's UID
exports.createIndividualUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) =>
{
  let email = user.email
  let uid = user.uid

  return  db.collection("Individuals").doc(uid).set(  // admin.database().ref('/Individuals').child.set(
    {
      Email: email,
      UID: uid
    }
  )
})
```

Here's terminal error when testing function:

```
firebase > createIndividual({email: "test1@test.com", password: "testworks!"})
Sent request to function.
firebase > !  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
!  functions: FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at app (C:\Users\pkerv\Documents\back-end\Stakkid\functions\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:358:33)
    at Object.serviceNamespace [as auth] (C:\Users\pkerv\Documents\back-end\Stakkid\functions\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:409:51)
    at C:\Users\pkerv\Documents\back-end\Stakkid\functions\index.js:22:15
    at C:\Users\pkerv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:573:20
    at C:\Users\pkerv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:548:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\pkerv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\pkerv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
    at runFunction (C:\Users\pkerv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:545:12)
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add your firebase admin sdk key to your project. You need to generate a credentials for your service account from you firebase project settings at https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk and then change your initialise app similar to the example below:

From:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    let db = admin.firestore();
```

To:

```
     const admin = require('firebase-admin');    
     const serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

     admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```